# Numpy: Replace every value in the array with the mean of its adjacent elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an ndarray, and I want to replace every value in the array with the mean of its adjacent elements. The code below can do the job, but it is super slow when I have 700 arrays all with shape (7000, 7000) , so I wonder if there are better ways to do it. Thanks!

```
a = np.array(([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]))
row,col = a.shape
new_arr = np.ndarray(a.shape)
for x in xrange(row):
    for y in xrange(col):
        min_x = max(0, x-1)
        min_y = max(0, y-1)
        new_arr[x][y] = a[min_x:(x+2),min_y:(y+2)].mean()
print new_arr
```

Comment: It's not running slowly for me at all, nor does it look like it should run slowly.

Comment: @EliSadoff it will if I have 700 arrays all with shape (7000,7000) ...

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in python but have you considered multi-threading or parallel processing? I know in C you can do this to speed up large data processing.

Comment: You are not setting `max_x` and `max_y` correctly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, that's a [`smoothing operation in image processing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing), which can be achieved with `2D` convolution. You are working a bit differently on the near-boundary elements. So, if the boundary elements are let off for precision, you can use [`scipy's convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) like so -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

out = (conv2(a,np.ones((3,3)),'same')/9.0
```

This specific operation is a built-in in OpenCV module as [`cv2.blur`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur) and is very efficient at it. The name basically describes its operation of blurring the input arrays representing images. I believe the efficiency comes from the fact that internally its implemented entirely in `C` for performance with a thin Python wrapper to handle NumPy arrays.

So, the output could be alternatively calculated with it, like so -

```
import cv2 # Import OpenCV module

out = cv2.blur(a.astype(float),(3,3))
```

Here's a quick show-down on timings on a decently big image/array -

```
In [93]: a = np.random.randint(0,255,(5000,5000)) # Input array

In [94]: %timeit conv2(a,np.ones((3,3)),'same')/9.0
1 loops, best of 3: 2.74 s per loop

In [95]: %timeit cv2.blur(a.astype(float),(3,3))
1 loops, best of 3: 627 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nicely done. I was about to write something like this. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Good to see you with NumPy tag! ;)

Comment: @Divakar It's on my feed :) I haven't been answering questions lately though... lots of stuff going on on my end.

Comment: [uniform_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter.html) is a short-cut for this... but since the `signal` module operates in the Fourier domain, I guess this would be faster?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Ah uniform_filter seems much faster! Post that as a solution!

Comment: @Divakar I guess.. if `uniform_filter` is faster it must be because it does two 1D convolutions (by separating the kernel). I will check something before :P

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Yeah, I am not sure about the internals of it, could be that.

Comment: @Divakar [just checked](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L765), internally it calls N times (one for dimension) to `uniform_filter1d`, which is probably why it gets the speedup over the `signal` module. For all other non-separable filters, your `conv2d` should always be faster.

Comment: Thanks @ImanolLuengo and Divakar for the answers! One more question, if I want to change mean to max, do you know what commands can do this? There doesn't seem to have max option in convolve2d...

Comment: @Chiefscreation Well there is max filter too in scipy : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html

Answer (score 4):

Following the discussion with @Divakar, find bellow a comparison of different convolution methods present in scipy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal, ndimage

def conv2(A, size):
    return signal.convolve2d(A, np.ones((size, size)), mode='same') / float(size**2)

def fftconv(A, size):
    return signal.fftconvolve(A, np.ones((size, size)), mode='same') / float(size**2)

def uniform(A, size):
    return ndimage.uniform_filter(A, size, mode='constant')
```

All 3 methods return exactly the same value. However, note that `uniform_filter` has a parameter `mode='constant'`, which indicates the boundary conditions of the filter, and `constant == 0` is the same boundary condition that the Fourier domain (in the other 2 methods) is enforced. For different use cases you can change the boundary conditions.

Now some test matrices:

```
A = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
```

And some timings:

```
%timeit conv2(A, 3)     # 33.8 ms per loop
%timeit fftconv(A, 3)   # 84.1 ms per loop
%timeit uniform(A, 3)   # 17.1 ms per loop

%timeit conv2(A, 5)     # 68.7 ms per loop
%timeit fftconv(A, 5)   # 92.8 ms per loop
%timeit uniform(A, 5)   # 17.1 ms per loop

%timeit conv2(A, 10)     # 210 ms per loop
%timeit fftconv(A, 10)   # 86 ms per loop
%timeit uniform(A, 10)   # 16.4 ms per loop

%timeit conv2(A, 30)     # 1.75 s per loop
%timeit fftconv(A, 30)   # 102 ms per loop
%timeit uniform(A, 30)   # 16.5 ms per loop
```

So in short, `uniform_filter` seems faster, and it because the [convolution is separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) in two 1D convolutons (similar to [gaussian_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter) which is also separable).

Other non-separable filters with different kernels are more likely to be faster using `signal` module (the one in @Divakar's) solution.

The speed of both `fftconvolve` and `uniform_filter` remains *constant* for different kernel sizes, while `convolve2d` gets slightly slower.

Comment: Good findings! Gotta digest all that stuffs now.

Comment: @Divakar just found something quite interesting, for different *small* kernel sizes, the last 2 methods maintain *constant* execution time.

Comment: I think I understood the uniform_filter's implementation with two passes to process this. That `fftconvolve`'s internal implementation looks messy though. Thanks again for coming up with those useful findings!

Comment: @Divakar [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) actually explains pretty well what `uniform_filter` is doing (essentially same example)!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and had to find a different solution since I can't use scipy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(100, size=(7000,7000)) #Array of 7000 x 7000
row,col = a.shape

column_totals =  a.sum(axis=0) #Dump the sum of all columns into a single array

new_array = np.zeros([row,col]) #Create an receiving array

for i in range(row):
    #Resulting row = the value of all rows minus the orignal row, divided by the row number minus one. 
    new_array[i] = (column_totals - a[i]) / (row - 1)

print(new_array)
```