# python convolution with different dimension

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement convolutional neural network in Python.
However, when I use signal.convolve or np.convolve, it can not do convolution on X, Y(X is 3d, Y is 2d). X are training minibatches. Y are filters.
I don't want to do for loop for every training vector like:

```
for i in xrange(X.shape[2]):
    result = signal.convolve(X[:,:,i], Y, 'valid')
    ....
```

So, is there any function I can use to do convolution efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

Scipy implements standard N-dimensional convolutions, so that the matrix to be convolved and the kernel are both N-dimensional.

A quick fix would be to add an extra dimension to `Y` so that `Y` is 3-Dimensional:

```
result = signal.convolve(X, Y[..., None], 'valid')
```

I'm assuming here that the last axis corresponds to the image index as in your example `[width, height, image_idx]` (or `[height, width, image_idx]`). If it is the other way around and the images are indexed in the first axis (as it is more common in C-ordering arrays) you should replace `Y[..., None]` with `Y[None, ...]`.

The line `Y[..., None]` will add an extra axis to `Y`, making it 3-dimensional `[kernel_width, kernel_height, 1]` and thus, converting it to a valid 3-Dimensional convolution kernel.

NOTE: This assumes that all your input mini-batches have the same `width x height`, which is standard in CNN's.

---

EDIT: Some timings as @Divakar suggested.

The testing framework is setup as follows:

```
def test(S, N, K):
    """ S: image size, N: num images, K: kernel size"""
    a = np.random.randn(S, S, N)
    b = np.random.randn(K, K)
    valid = [slice(K//2, -K//2+1), slice(K//2, -K//2+1)]

    %timeit signal.convolve(a, b[..., None], 'valid')
    %timeit signal.fftconvolve(a, b[..., None], 'valid')
    %timeit ndimage.convolve(a, b[..., None])[valid]
```

Find bellow tests for different configurations:

- Varying image size `S`:

  ```
  >>> test(100, 50, 11) # 100x100 images
  1 loop, best of 3: 909 ms per loop
  10 loops, best of 3: 116 ms per loop
  10 loops, best of 3: 54.9 ms per loop

  >>> test(1000, 50, 11) # 1000x1000 images
  1 loop, best of 3: 1min 51s per loop
  1 loop, best of 3: 16.5 s per loop
  1 loop, best of 3: 5.66 s per loop
  ```
- Varying number of images `N`:

  ```
  >>> test(100, 5, 11) # 5 images
  10 loops, best of 3: 90.7 ms per loop
  10 loops, best of 3: 26.7 ms per loop
  100 loops, best of 3: 5.7 ms per loop

  >>> test(100, 500, 11) # 500 images
  1 loop, best of 3: 9.75 s per loop
  1 loop, best of 3: 888 ms per loop
  1 loop, best of 3: 727 ms per loop
  ```
- Varying kernel size `K`:

  ```
  >>> test(100, 50, 5) # 5x5 kernels
  1 loop, best of 3: 217 ms per loop
  10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop
  100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop

  >>> test(100, 50, 31) # 31x31 kernels
  1 loop, best of 3: 4.39 s per loop
  1 loop, best of 3: 220 ms per loop
  1 loop, best of 3: 560 ms per loop
  ```

So, in short, `ndimage.convolve` is always faster, except when the kernel size is very large (as `K = 31` in the last test).

Comment: Good find! For a faster version use `ndimage.filters.convolve(X,Y[...,None])` maybe with some slicing?

Comment: @Divakar it would be nice to time it (I'll do it if I can get some time), but I think that `ndimage,filters.convolve` should be slower for large kernel sizes (as it does convolution in the spatial domain whereas `signal.convolve` does it in the fourier domain). The advantage of the `ndimage` filters are that support different boundary conditions (different from fourier which I think that by definition is equivalent to padding the image with 0s). I'll do the timings asap!

Comment: @Divakar tests done! I'm feeling like this is some kind of dejavu. As you suggested, `ndimage.convolve` tends to be faster in general. I remember having a similar conversation about this in a different thread haha

Comment: You know what that's good memory and not just dejavu! ;) Here's the post I think you were referring to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38232755/3293881

Comment: @Divakar Haha exactly that one yes! That time I was proposing `uniform_filter` over `signal.convolve` lol. Although `uniform_filter` was faster due to the *separability* of the kernels, the above results seem to confirm the conclusion we arrived in that thread: for large kernel sizes fourier (fftconvolve) > spatial, if not spatial > fourier.

Comment: Yup! That theory prevails here! :D